# Rails 5 HABTM Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm throwing in the towel after a day of getting nowhere (and the answer will likely be annoyingly simple, but that's code).

Ok, I have 2 models, User (with Devise) and Chapter.

#### Models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_and_belongs_to_many :chapters
end

class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

#### _form.html.erb

```
[...]
<% @chapter.users.each_with_index do |chap_user, i| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4  col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <small>User <%= i + 1 %></small>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4  col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">

      <div class="field form-group">
        <%= form.label 'First Name' %>
        <%= form.text_field :first_name, value: chap_user.first_name,class:"form-control"%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <div class="field form-group">
        <%= form.label 'Last Name' %>
        <%= form.text_field :last_name, value: chap_user.last_name, class:"form-control"%>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <div class="field form-group">
        <%= form.label :email %>
        <%= form.text_field :email, value: chap_user.email, class:"form-control"%>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
[...]
```

#### ChaptersController (params)

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_chapter
      @chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])
    end

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def chapter_params
  params.fetch(:chapter, {})
  params.require(:chapter).permit(:city, :country_id, user_attributes: [:first_name,:last_name,:email])
end
# or...
params.require(:chapter).permit(:city, :country_id, user_ids: [])
# or...
params.require(:chapter).permit(:city, :country_id, user_attributes: [:id, :first_name])
# or...
params.require(:chapter).permit(:city, :country_id, users_attributes: [:id, :first_name])
```

#### binding.pry in controller

```
  # PATCH/PUT /chapters/1
  # PATCH/PUT /chapters/1.json
  def update
    binding.pry
    respond_to do |format|
      if @chapter.update(chapter_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @chapter, notice: 'Chapter was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @chapter }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @chapter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

#### binding.pry response

I know this one is a bit ugly but basically the params are being submitted but users[:first_name,:last_name,:email] aren't being permitted

[1] pry(#)> chapter_params 
Unpermitted parameters: :first_name, :last_name, :email => "London", "country_id"=>"1"} permitted: true>
[2] pry(#)> params => "✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"9IdAqcAsVG5vvakSf7jHRk+WplN/GyVZUxmAdefUbTX/uI6IajmZPr1YSol21Zhzdl7P/lrl+SVnWr5mBMiljw==", "chapter"=>"London", "country_id"=>"1", "first_name"=>"Tim2", "last_name"=>"Heard", "email"=>"jmcgregorx@spartaglobal.com"} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Update", "controller"=>"chapters", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1"} permitted: false>

In a nutshell, I want to connect certain users to certain chapters through a form, but I can't figure out how to get the nested params through the chapter update/create methods. My head is a red, pulpy mess. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the fields you are trying to modify are for a child model, you have to tell the form that because it assumes that you're editing fields on parent model by default. The way to to that is [by using #fields_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) (specifically the the "One-to-Many" section).

So you'll do something along these lines (explanation below code):

```
<% @chapter.users.each_with_index do |chap_user, i| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :users, chap_user do |user_fields| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4  col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <small>User <%= i+ 1 %></small>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4  col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="field form-group">
          <%= user_fields.label 'First Name' %>
          <%= user_fields.text_field :first_name, value: chap_user.first_name,class:"form-control"%>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="field form-group">
          <%= user_fields.label 'Last Name' %>
          <%= user_fields.text_field :last_name, value: chap_user.last_name, class:"form-control"%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="field form-group">
          <%= user_fields.label :email %>
          <%= user_fields.text_field :email, value: chap_user.email, class:"form-control"%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What changed is I wrapped all the form inputs in a block using the `#fields_for` method to specify that now we're modifying child attributes. When we do so, we also specify a variable name that will be used to generate fields for the child model's attributes. I named it `user_fields` and then inside that block replaced all references of `form` with `user_fields`.

In your ChaptersController, you want the line that accepts the params to be:

```
params.require(:chapter).permit(:city, :country_id, users_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email])
```

You'd want `users_attributes` and not `user_attribute` because the plural "users" tells rails to expect attributes for more than one child (more than one user). Then inside that array you want to tell it all the fields to expect, including `id`. Even though you're not explicitly defining a field for the ID, Rails puts one to allow you to edit attributes for children that already exist (and not only be able to create new ones). Snippet from the documentation:

> Note that #fields_for will automatically generate a hidden field to store the ID of the record. There are circumstances where this hidden field is not needed and you can pass include_id: false to prevent #fields_for from rendering it automatically.

If something about this doesn't work, or if you have more questions, feel free to let me know!

Comment: Hi @bwalshy, first thanks for your reply. Second, unfortunately it hasn't worked. I changed my code to yours and added <%= chap_user.first_name %> after the first line of your reply to check I was getting the users, which I am. But nothing is printing after that, from form.fields_for afterwards. 

Would it be something to do with this line:
form.fields_for :users, chap_user do |user_fields|

Comment: Whoops, I didn't have an equal sign at that line to say to print the form fields. You want: `<%= form.fields_for :users, chap_user do |user_fields| %>`. (an equal sign after the `<%`. I'll update my answer too

Comment: I also updated my answer to show what the controller params should look like (and why)